# SQL Access - Any way to update my table using a percent value?

Tags: sql, ms-access

**Question**
`After increasing the rental fee of each large slip by $150 (Exercise 3), Alexamara decides to decrease the rental fee of any slip whose fee is more than $4,000 by one percent. Update the rental fees in the LARGE_SLIP table accordingly.`

I have a command that works, but I don't know if this is how the book is wanting me to do it:

```
update LARGE_SLIP set RENTAL_FEE = RENTAL_FEE - 42 where RENTAL_FEE = '4200';
```

This works because there are only two records in the table with a rental fee of over 4000, and they both have rental fees of 4200. I would like to know if there is command I can use that would cause the rental fee discount of 1% to be applied to any fee over 4000, Something like:

```
update LARGE_SLIP set RENTAL_FEE = RENTAL_FEE - 1% where RENTAL_FEE > '4000';
```

I cannot figure out how to get this kind of command to work properly, or if one even exists.

Comment: `RENTAL_FEE * 0.99`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update LARGE_SLIP set RENTAL_FEE = RENTAL_FEE*0.99 where RENTAL_FEE > 4000;
```

or

```
update LARGE_SLIP set RENTAL_FEE = RENTAL_FEE-RENTAL_FEE*0.01 where RENTAL_FEE > 4000;
```

i removed the quotes in 4000 because it is highly unlikely that you can put a char in conditional statement of numerics.

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed! Thank you for your help. I will accept this answer as soon as it lets me.